# Is it bad practice to put application specific modules into a second node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, organization, modularity

I'm trying to restructure some of my application components to make them more easily available inside of my project. (eg. not having to stack '../../../' in my requires). I have set up a second node_modules folder at the second level of my project hierarchy where I want to put my application specific modules into, that I use frequently from any point of the project (eg. a module providing my app's config values).

Now I wonder if this is to be considered a bad practice as node modules inside node_modules folders are meant to be independent, global modules, to be used in any project. Is this true? Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: instead of manually making a folder in `node_modules` keep your application code in a separately testable repository. you can install node modules from git and have scoped dependencies in npm

Comment: What you're trying to do is most likely a bad practice due to the reasons you listed. Your question is a bit opinion-based, but [this](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) will probably help you a great deal (option 3 is quite elegant).